# how to use find (or other command) to extract a number after underscore in a filename

Tags: bash, find, counter

This should be a quick one for people who can code, unlike me...

I'm trying to write a basic bash script where it will:

(i) look at the number of a single file called counter_ e.g. counter_1, counter_2 in a directory and extract the number after the _
(ii) create a new variable from the extracted number to control a task
(iii) save a new counter to the same location with an increment of 1
(iv) repeat

i.e. if counter_1 is the file in the location:

```
find /path/to/file -name 'counter_*' | some magic that extracts the digits after the _|
CounterNumber="number extracted above"

# my script here using the CounterNumber variable

rm  /path/to/file/counter_$CounterNumber
touch /path/to/file/counter_$(CounterNumber+1)
```

And so on with the process repeating for counter_2

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: assuming your `find` command works as desired, and the filename is always `counter_<number>`: `CounterNumber=$(find ... | cut -d"_" -f2)`; to increment the variable: `CounterNumber=$((CounterNumber+1))`

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

CounterNumber=$(find /path/file -name 'counter_*' | cut -d"_" -f2)
CounterNumber=$((CounterNumber+1))

Answer (score 0):

```
CounterNumber="$(find /path/to/file -name 'counter_*' | awk -F_ 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$NF} END{print sum}')"
# your script...
rm "/path/to/file/counter_$CounterNumber"
touch "/path/to/file/counter_$((CounterNumber+1))"
```

Let's break down the `awk` call on the first line;

```
awk -F_ 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$NF} END{print sum}'
```

From [`man awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

> -F fs
>
> --field-separator fs
>
> ```
> Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
> ```

This means that `awk` will split the text on `_`, if `-F` isn't specified blank space will be used by default.

The `BEGIN` part of the `awk` expression will run *once*, before doing any processing. In here, we initialize a variable that will keep track of our sum,

The second `{}` group will run for every line fed to `awk`, update the variable `sum` with the last field. In this case `$1` = `counter`, `$2` (and also the last field, `$NF`) is what ever the number was.

The `END` part of the expression will run *once*, before `awk` will exit, so just print out the value of `sum`.